# aws s3api put-bucket-encryption cli command adds extra quotes when in cmd

Tags: aws-cli

When I use the the following command in cmd to add bucket encryption to a certain bucket in my account there is additions quotes that show up and the command never really works. Other s3api command are working just fine.

**Command I type:**

```
aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket MyBucket --server-side-encryption-configuration '{"Rules": [{"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault": {"SSEAlgorithm": "AES256"}}]}'
```

**What happens when I hit enter:**

```
> aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket MyBucket --server-side-encryption-configuration ''"'"'{Rules:' '[{ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault:' '{SSEAlgorithm:' 'AES256}}]}'"'"''
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong in the AWScli?

Eventually once I have the command right I want to code it into my c# program but that will be another question.

Comment: What exit code you get after running this command?
Can you provide more info about your terminal and your shell config? This looks like an environmental issue.

Comment: @Michal usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: {SSEAlgorithm:, AES256}}]}', [{ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault:

Comment: I am using cmd opened as admin

Comment: In powershell I get the following:   Error parsing parameter '--server-side-encryption-configuration': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
JSON received: {Rules: [{ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault: {SSEAlgorithm: AES256}}]}

Comment: Oh, you're using windows. I thought you are using linux so you can provide exit code and shell setup. Anyway. As you can see your powershell suggestion is an environment issue.
Try to use `\"` instead of just `"`, like:
`aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket MyBucket --server-side-encryption-configuration '{\"Rules\": [{\"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault\": {\"SSEAlgorithm\": \"AES256\"}}]}'`

Comment: Thank you very much @Michal.  Works like a charm. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

For the record: Problem can be solved by escaping double quotes with backslash in JSON section:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket MyBucket --server-side-encryption-configuration '{\"Rules\": [{\"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault\": {\"SSEAlgorithm\": \"AES256\"}}]}'
```